# setting system variables in MySQL running as docker container

Tags: mysql, docker, dockerhub

I have used docker to setup mysql server taken from https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/mysql/ , I know that we can set up environment variables using several options while running an image as"-e , -env or --env-file" which works absolutely fine as I want. But now I want to edit my system variables for MySQL say "max_connections=300". Is there a way we can use these options to achieve this. I have tried using --env-file option to update system variables but no success :( would be really very helpful if anyone can give pointers on this.

Thanks,
~yash

Answer (score 3):

From description of mysql docker container:

You can pass arbitrary command line options to the MySQL server by appending them to the run command:

```
docker run --name my-container-name -d mysql/mysql-server --option1=value --option2=value
```

In this case, the values of option1 and option2 will be passed directly to the server when it is started. The following command will for instance start your container with UTF-8 as the default setting for character set and collation for all databases in MySQL:

```
docker run --name my-container-name -d mysql/mysql-server --character-set-server=utf8 --collation-server=utf8_general_ci
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at, for example https://github.com/skarllot/docker-mysql/blob/master/assets/my.cnf.template for a specific value for max_connections, and for the Dockerfile https://github.com/skarllot/docker-mysql

Comment: Hi, Thank-you so much for response. what i understand from this image is that we are defining environment variables and their values inside docker image  in "default.sh" file and for changing any value each time we will have to build a new container. Please correct me if I am wrong. What I want here is have a common docker image and while running it user can provide configurable parameters dynamically which will finally be used for MySQL server. Would be waiting for the response.....